# manager.GetIOSettings() -> None in Mac Python FBX SDK bindings

Tags: python, fbx

Fresh install of the python bindings for the FBX SDK on a Mac, into site-packages of an anaconda python 2.7.12 installation. Success when importing fbx and FbxCommon. Success creating manager, scene, and importer objects for an fbx file import. here's the code

```
import fbx

manager = fbx.FbxManager.Create()
iosettings = manager.GetIOSettings()
scene = fbx.FbxScene.Create(manager, "")
importer = fbx.FbxImporter.Create(manager, "")

fname = 'test.fbx'
if not importer.Initialize(fname, -1, iosettings):
    print "INITIALIZE ", importer.GetStatus().GetErrorString()
if not importer.Import(scene):
    print "IMPORT ", importer.GetStatus().GetErrorString()
```

But... manager.GetIOSettings() returns None rather than something usable. I am still able to import some files (others, with errors, are for another question), so maybe this is not a showstopper, but still...

Any ideas about iosettings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the manager does not have an IOSettings, you can create one for it:

```
if not manager.GetIOSettings():
    ios = fbx.FbxIOSettings.Create(manager, fbx.IOSROOT)
    manager.SetIOSettings(ios)
```

(discovered in the FbxCommon.py file from the python SDK bindings)